# Low ping, but delay in-game seemingly random

Tags: dota-2

I'm not experiencing any issue with other applications.

Here is what the top-right system HUD tells me right now:

```
 FPS / PING  60  25
LOSS / KBPS   0  190
```

The bottom right number reached about 2000 when Tinker used march, although I could not reproduce that.

When I'm experiencing delay, the `ping` stays the same while only the `kbps` increases.

- OS: Windows 10
- Bandwidth: 30/1

Let me know if there are other things I should give to help debug.

Comment: Hmm Diablo 2 is very low demanding game considering modern computing power. KBPS is kilobit per second which means diablo 2 is transfering a lot of data during those burst. Can you explain what you meant by tinker used march?

Comment: This is Dota 2. If `kbps` is just that, then what does the loss refers to?

Comment: Oh sorry I don't know why I thought diablo 2. Loss is how many packet made the trip. IE if 100 packet were sent and Loss is at 0 then none was lost. If 100 sent and Loss is at 50 then 50 got through. In your case although 0 Loss is a good sign.

Comment: Are these short ping spikes (maybe 2-5 seconds)? Or long, drawn out periods of increased lag? If the former, it's probably your connection that's bad - either reset your modem/router or talk to your ISP and let them know you're having problems. If the latter, make sure you don't have other programs downloading updates in the background - both Steam and Windows Update are usually the culprits when I experience lag like that.

Comment: @MageXy Yesterday for instance, I'd get delays (varying from .5 to 2 seconds) every minute or so. Once it got very long, about 10 seconds where nothing was moving (heroes running but not advancing) but I had the live sound. Then my router restarted itself, or was blinky like when I restart it and I got the red banner "something something Dota coordinator".

Comment: In situation you described, only one thing may be: server. Try another region in server selection dialog, even if it will to some increase in ping it displays. Try this and share feedback

Comment: I've been getting the same, and my PC/Intenet are well above anything dota should requires - one thing I noticed is that quitting dota entirely, closing any chat programs, and restarting seems to solve it at least temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

Try using another account. It might seem dumb but even pro players (Arteezy and EternalEnvy) had something in their Steam Cloud that led to *extreme* input delay and lag while having standard pings and no packet loss.

If changing accounts fixes it, Google about erasing Steam Cloud data, it's fairly easy and you just have to follow a guide step-by-step.

Comment: Interesting. What would cloud data contain as far as Dota 2 goes exactly? I'm guessing key bindings mostly. What about 1. in-game item builds 2. Graphic/audio/gameplay settings?

Comment: @MathieuMarques I honestly have no clue, but I do know that Arteezy was once forced to play a Pro-Game with a different account because of this, it was then fixed by some Valve employee, but that's not going to happen for a normal user like us, this is why we have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

So you are playing Dota 2 ver 7+ ?

- Have you checked the graphical requirements of the game?
- Have you checked your connection to the server? ( not just your internet connection, because the server is sometimes slow )
- Have you patched your game correctly?

The casting animation, attack animation, skill animation namely any animation will cause a spike in your kbps.  If more than one animation is present and can be seen on screen this will spike your games kbps.  If your connection speed to the server is not that good it will spike.

I have had this happen to me a lot of times.  This also used to happen a lot in Dota 1.  Spectre, Zeus and most massive moving animation skills will stutter and spike your game.

Also since Dota 2 loads different characters with lots of different cosmetic items.  Which also animate differently from each other so you also get a spike there.

So sometimes its your connection which is trying to catch up to the animation from the server.  Other times its just the game and a patch was not installed correctly and has caused some kind of problem.  Most times its just the computer not being able to handle the graphics.

Edit:
You should also check if you have any background applications working during gameplay.  Check if the Steam client is downloading something while in the background.  Also try to test your ping to the server using this: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=217075877

Comment: 1. I run with the highest settings at 60 FPS. 2. The ping is always low (in-game and in the server selection dialog. 3. What do you mean by that? I let steam update the game itself.

Comment: @MathieuMarques Try playing the game with the basic video settings first to test it out.  Then move it up little by little until you hit the best spot for the graphics.  Also check your system if it is using the best 3D settings for the game.  I also use a high end PC in a gaming cafe used by Pro-gamers to play Dota 2 and I still get these kinds of error.  I set it first to the lowest settings then tweak it up as I go.  You might also have a problem connecting to the server you play in but don't know about it.

Comment: Best 3D settings? Wouldn't the FPS suffer from it as well if my settings where to high? How do I check a problem in the connection with the server (I'm usually the only one having issues in the the game)?

Comment: @MathieuMarques The best thing to do is ask your Internet Service Provider.  Sometimes they tweak their systems and it is just they have a problem in the connection and they don't know about it.  1) call your ISP to check your internet connection for Dota 2.  2) Check your graphics settings.  3) Use these guides: a) https://www.killping.com/blog/how-to-overcome-dota-2-lag-and-packet-loss/ b) https://www.killping.com/blog/fix-dota-2-lag-with-good-internet/

Comment: Graphics and ping have nothing to do with each other (unless the game is coded really bizarrely, which probably isn't the case for Valve-produced DotA2). FPS stuttering and lag spikes are two different problems. You could argue that having more actions happening on screen is related to increased kbps, but only because the server (and you, the client) needs to know about multiple abilities going off, so more data is sent.